# Как удержать бегунок ScrollBar постоянно внизу

Tags: delphi

На форме есть компонент `DBGrid`, в который в среднем каждые полсекунды добавляется строка лога БД. При этом, прочитать последние записи не представляется возможным, т.к. после каждого добавления записи бегунок возвращается в начало и видно только первые строки.

Лучшее что пришло в голову, как то заставить грид обновляться не на каждое изменение, а, скажем, раз в 3 секунды. А реализовать как то прямо это тоже не вышло, просто отключал грид от сорса, но это тоже ничего не дало.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с этим бороться?

Comment: Отсортировал данные задом наперед, стали добавляться сверху, вроди бы и нормально и даже логичнее, видно все новые записи, но у начальства вопрос стал принципиально, вопрос актуален

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть способ проше после обновления данных (или по таймеру через каждые 3 секунды) сделать

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Last
```

А насчет этого

> добавления записи бегунок
> возвращается в начало
> если делать

```
DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh
```

бегунок останенся на месте

еще есть метод
DBGrid1.ScrollBy();

но этот метод при больших таблицах иногда глючит

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно попробую и отпишу результаты

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так:

Объект TWMVSCROLL:

> var Mes: TWMVSCROLL;

Код:

> Mes.Msg:=WM_VSCROLL;
>
> Mes.ScrollCode:=SB_BOTTOM;

при добавлении записи делаем:

> DBGrid1.Dispatch(Mes);

Сообщаем компоненту где должен быть скролл. Писал здесь так как нету под рукой делфи.
Но принцип должен быть ясен.

Comment: Делал я так. Фигня получается. В любом случае, когда обновляется грид, бегунок уходит вверх, по диспатчу уходит вниз, и вот так вот мечется постоянно. А теберь представьте картину, когда происходит несколько добавлений в секунду... ) Но за ответ спасибо, всегда ценил этот ресурс за отзывчивость )

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя ли переписать прогу которая добавляет записи в твою БД.
Наверно у тебя там чтото типа

```
TableX.Insert
...................
TableX.Post
```

Попробуй

```
TableX.Append
........................
TableX.Post
```

При таком методе строка добавляется и автоматически Грид переходит в конец!